# Compiling C++ for MacOSX 10.5 and 10.6

Tags: c++, macos

I have a reasonably simple C++ program that I can successfully compile on OSX 10.6 using:

```
g++ -O3 -funroll-loops -I /usr/local/include/boost-1_39/ myfile.cpp -o build/myfile
```

However, a user on OSX 10.5 gets the error:

```
dyld: unknown required load command
```

A [support forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2319912) suggests adding

```
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
```

However adding this seems to mess with my include paths and gives me tons of errors.  Is there an easy way to compile a binary that will work on OSX 10.5 and 10.6?

Comment: How do I close/delete my own question?

Comment: If you can detail some of the errors you are seeing, that might help.

Comment: you should be able to vote to close your own question. Alternatively you could extend your answer with how you solved your problem / what your problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questions has been solved, I believe, using the suggested command.